# Proving measurability of integral of two variables w.r.t. x

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f(x,y)$ be a nonnegative continuous function on $[0,1]^2$. For any borel set $B \subset [0,1]$, let
$$
\lambda(x, B) = \int_Bf(x ,y) dy
$$
where dy denotes integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure. 
I have to prove that for any borel set B $\lambda(x, B)$ isa borel map as a function of x.

**What I have in mind:**
I know that $f$ is continuous, so $f$ should be continuous for a fixed x. I know by a previous proposition that a section of a borel map is still a borel map. I think what confuses me is the fact that integration is with respect to y only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is part of the proof of Fubini's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an exercise one may use a version of the FMCT (Theorem 5.2.2 [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)) to see that $x\mapsto \lambda(x,\cdot)$ is measurable for any bounded, measurable function on $[0,1]^2$. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the set of functions $f$ for which the latter map is Borel measurable. (1) For $f(x,y)=1_A(x)1_C(y)$, where $A$ and $C$ are Borel subsets of $[0,1]$,
$$
\lambda(x,B)=1_A(x)\int1_{C\cap B}(y)\,dy
$$
is clearly measurable and so $1_{A\times C}\in \mathcal{H}$. (2) $\mathcal{H}$ is stable under addition and pointwise increasing limits (by the linearity of $\int$ and the monotone convergence theorem). Therefore, $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded measurable functions.